# OS environment variables are not updated per host in java

Tags: java, environment-variables

The following static variable is not refreshed each time on app start up:

```
class Test {
    private static final String TEST_DIR = System.getenv("HOME") + "/files/";

..
}
```

It seems like upon building the jar the 'HOME' variable is read and stored in the TEST_DIR string and the logic for reading the variable is no longer executed.

So moving the jar to an other host will break the application.

Comment: it is not possible. your HOME env is always the same

Comment: "it seems that"... How should we know? The code you are showing will compute that constant once on startup, and its value will depend on that env var. The code is correct, if the results are not, then something else in your setup is wrong. Or simply the expectation that HOME results in different directoy names on different machines. Which is mist likely a flawed assumption.

Comment: On Windows processes inherit the environment variables from the parent process. If you change an entry (e.g. via Windows control panel) it only gets propagates to those processes that listen for such changes (e.g. the explorer.exe processes). The other processes will keep on using the old version and if such a process starts a new process it gets also the old version.